# Tools to diagnose browser differences and problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

What are some tool to help uncover why for instance FF is rendering a page differently than chrome ie and safari. My issue is simply the images along the left side of my main body get stretched to the length of the page only in FF every other browser renders in perfectly!

If anyone cares to see the difference

http://tinyurl.com/7vkcvn5
Works in everything but FF

Comment: I think you're layout needs to be div layout...Everything becomes much more simpler then...you have two columns - one with images, the other with content and everything will line up perfectly in all browsers. Table layouts are a thing of the past and frankly, they will trouble later in other browsers if used for layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes have luck running a page that is exhibiting quirks through a validator just to check that there isn't a typo or something triggering the problem. Try http://validator.w3c.org/. Your page has many validation errors in it, so that could explain the rendering quirks.  (Some people argue, correctly in my opinion, that in some situations validation errors are OK. This doesn't strike me as one of those situations.)

Might not answer your specific alignment issue, but for differences in browser support, I usually go to http://quirksmode.org/ and http://caniuse.com/.  To find polyfills to patch over browser differences, I usually go to http://html5please.com/.

Comment: i was hoping for something that would analysis what i have and give me some feedback any ideas @trott

Comment: You're not going to find something, and certainly not for free, that will do static analysis on your web site and indicate where you are maybe triggering different layout in Firefox.  Doubly so if the different layout is not wrong.  You will find tools, though, that will tell you where you have errors in your HTML. I've added one to my answer.

Comment: thanks man tried it out fixed some errors still cant get find my error but ill shall keep trying! thanks again for the tools though!@Trott

Answer (score 0):

browserstack.com

and

spoon.net/browsers

are two of the best tools I have been using.